# shuttle in zsh terminal on MacOS: "expected server init string b'SSHUTTLE0001'; got b''"

Tags: macos, ssh, dns, zsh, macos-big-sur

So what I'm entering is:

```
 sshuttle --dns -x xxx.xx.xx.xxx -r MyUsername@x.x.x.x 10.101.0.0/16 10.102.0.0/16
```

But what I'm getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "assembler.py", line 18, in <module>
TypeError: module.__init__() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
client: fatal: expected server init string b'SSHUTTLE0001'; got b''
```

Please help me, I've tried searching the forums before but nothing seems to be helping me.

I have tried brew install shuttle / port install shuttle and they've both given me the standard install messages.

I can get info on the remote system but as far as I knew they used many versions of Python, 2 and 3 at least.

Answer (score 2):

Mela

It seems that the issue is related to the sshuttle and servers with Python2. [It was fixed today](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html):

```
# 1.0.5 - 2020-12-29

## Added

IPv6 support in nft method.
Intercept DNS requests sent by systemd-resolved.
Set default tmark.
Fix python2 server compatibility.
Python 3.9 support.
```

We should upgrade sshuttle to fix the error

```
brew upgrade sshuttle
```

As a workaround, we can install Python3 on the remote server

```
# CentOS
yum install python3
```